# Strange vertical blank

Tags: spacing, hyperref

Typesetting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathptmx,hyperref}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, marginparsep=0.7cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\newtheorem{teor}{Teorema}

\begin{document}

\noindent Proseguendo su queste cose, parliamo di Decomposizione in Parte Libera e Parte di Torsione.
\begin{teor}
\end{teor}
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image: With hyperref]

whereas without `hyperref` I get:

[image: Without hyperref]

that is a significantly smaller amount of vertical space between the theorem and the top line. If I replace the theorem with another line, e.g. `\par s`, I don't get the big vertical space. Why does that happen?

**Update:**

Following egreg's answer, I tried loading `amsthm`, obtaining a strange error. Precisely, typesetting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{thmtools,amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definizione}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand\listtheoremname{Definizioni, Teoremi, Proposizioni, ecc.}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={defi}]
\end{document}
```

yields:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./gungugungu4.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-autoref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/aliasctr.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/remreset.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-listof.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-restate.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(./gungugungu4.aux)

Package thmtools Warning: amsthm loaded after thmtools .


Package thmtools Warning: ntheorem loaded after thmtools .

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./gungugungu4.out) (./gungugungu4.out)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

./gungugungu4.tex:9: Extra \else.
\@forloop ...lse #5\def #4{#2}\ifx #4\@nnil \else 
                                                  #5\@iforloop #3\@@ #4{#5}\...
l.9 \listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={defi}]
```

Loading `thmtools` *after* `amsthm` solves everything, and removing `hyperref` yields:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./gungugungu4.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-autoref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/aliasctr.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/remreset.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-listof.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-restate.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(./gungugungu4.aux)

Package thmtools Warning: amsthm loaded after thmtools .


Package thmtools Warning: ntheorem loaded after thmtools .

./gungugungu4.tex:9: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.9 \listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={defi}]
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Well, the warning tells you that `amsthm` must be loaded before `thmtools`. I get no error; but of course the example is not what you have, because it misses `\listoftheorems`. Please, don't radically change a question, but rather ask a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being unlucky. Because of the implementation of `\newtheorem` in the kernel, under some circumstances the *whatsit* generated by `hyperref` is issued in a place where it makes it impossible to remove the space at the end of the paragraph (generated by the end-of-line after `Torsione.`).

Here's a set of examples.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathptmx,hyperref}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, marginparsep=0.7cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\newtheorem{teor}{Teorema}

\begin{document}

\noindent Proseguendo su queste cose, parliamo di Decomposizione in Parte Libera e Parte di Torsione.
\begin{teor}
\end{teor}

\noindent Proseguendo su questo, parliamo di Decomposizione in Parte Libera e Parte di Torsione.
\begin{teor}
\end{teor}

\noindent Proseguendo su queste cose, parliamo di Decomposizione in Parte Libera e Parte di Torsione.

\begin{teor}
\end{teor}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So you see that the problem is caused by the line ending too near the right margin, because it doesn't happen in the second case.

Solution: always leave a blank line before `\begin{teor}`, which is also better for readability of the typescript.

Alternative solution: load also `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathptmx,hyperref}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, marginparsep=0.7cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\newtheorem{teor}{Teorema}

\begin{document}

\noindent Proseguendo su queste cose, parliamo di Decomposizione in Parte Libera e Parte di Torsione.
\begin{teor}
\end{teor}

\noindent Proseguendo su questo, parliamo di Decomposizione in Parte Libera e Parte di Torsione.
\begin{teor}
\end{teor}

\noindent Proseguendo su queste cose, parliamo di Decomposizione in Parte Libera e Parte di Torsione.

\begin{teor}
\end{teor}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I'd still recommend using the third way of inputting your code.

Comment: Loading `amsthm` works, only this MWE is the minimal reduction of a much more complex code where `thmtools` is loaded and `\listoftheorems` is used, and loading `amsthm` there yields:

`./app_Alg_2.tex:517: Extra \else.
\@forloop ...lse #5\def #4{#2}\ifx #4\@nnil \else 
#5\@iforloop #3\@@ #4{#5}\...
l.517 ...,oss,propo,coro,fatto,lemma,pt,riass,es}]`

What is _that_? Anyway the blank line solution works, so the problem's solved. But another solution works: putting `\hspace{-10pt}` at the end of the top line. Why?

Comment: @MickG Trying to solve the issue with `thmtools` is impossible, without details. Adding the negative space makes TeX think the line is shorter, so basically you're like in the second case.

Comment: I've added those details to the question.